# Avoid taking a value copy when creating a map element

Tags: c++

I have a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> foo`, the contents of which I build up slowly using a function

```
bar(
    std::string key   /*key name*/,
    std::size_t index /*element index of the vector*/,
    double value      /*value to put in the vector at that index*/
)
```

This function populates `foo` in a way that I trust is obvious from the function parameter types and those brief comments.

However, I'm concerned that when I'm adding a new key, which happens when I do this

```
auto it = foo.find(index);
if (it == foo.end()){
   /*ToDo - avoid taking a vector value copy*/
```

I end up creating a new `std::vector<double>`, and putting that in a map. And that results in my taking a value copy of that vector. Is there a way (other than using smart pointers as map values) of doing this without taking a value copy?

Comment: But it's not default constructed; I pass a size in and an element.

Comment: I have a nice new C++11 Stroustrup on my desk that cost our firm a lot of money. Drop by and read it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been a good way since C++11 (which, given your use of `auto`, you're using). This standard allows a special type of insertion called **emplacement**. The easiest way for you to exploit this would be to use

```
it = foo.emplace(
    std::make_pair(key, std::vector<double>(1 + index, 0.0/*a default value*/))
).first;
```

and then call `it->second.at(index) = value` which is something that you probably do anyway if `find` *does* return an element.

The emplacement technique is exploiting the move constructors of the anonymous temporary `std::vector` and the anonymous temporary `std::pair`. (Those temporaries are called **r-value references**).

For more details see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Comment: Boss, I think this is over-complicated. @timrau's answer is simpler no?

Comment: I don't know about "complicated" but emplacement is the standard solution for this problem. If you already had the vector initialized you could just std::move it in.

Comment: Possibly but you should get used to emplacements and `&&`. You could put a default vector on the map and then size it. That's how we would have done it in C++03.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::map::operator[]` which fetches the reference to value if the key exists, or create a new one if the key doesn't exist.

```
std::vector<double>& targetarray = foo[key];
// resize targetarray if required
targetarray[index] = value;
```